# Regarding Mongodb and ruby on rails

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to develop a web application using Ruby On Rails and Mongodb that allows users to enter values and save the values in Mongodb databases,I have working installation of both RoR and Mongodb.I am new to RoR and Mongodb please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you have a specific programming question, this question isn't a good fit for stack overflow, as it's asking for a complete walkthrough of many technologies. There are many tutorials on the internet for using these technologies. Have a look. Mongodb.org has a language center for Ruby. http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/ruby/

Answer (score 1):

From Mongodb documentation:

> Because MongoDB is so easy to use, the basic Ruby driver can be the
>   best solution for many applications.
>
> But if you need validations, associations, and other high-level data
>   modeling functions then an Object Document Mapper may be needed.
>
> In the context of a Rails application these provide functionality
>   equivalent to, but distinct from, ActiveRecord. Because MongoDB is a
>   document-based database, these mappers are called Object Document
>   Mappers (ODM) as opposed to Object Relational Mappers (ORM).
>
> Several mappers are available:
>
> - MongoMapper from John Nunemaker
> - Mongoid from Durran Jordan
> - Mongomatic from Ben Myles
> - MongoODM from Carlos Paramio
> - MongoModel from Sam Pohlenz
> - DriverAPILayer from Alexey Petrushin
>
> All the mappers build on top of the basic Ruby driver and so some
>   knowledge of that is useful, especially if you work with a custom
>   MongoDB configuration.

After you choose ODM, you can start your app, and following the ODM's documentation.

See [Mongoid rails documentation](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/rails.html) for example, and [Mongoid-Sample-Project](https://github.com/fullbridge-batkins/Bens-Mongoid-Sample-Project).

If you are new also in Rails, first read rails guides like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) or [this](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book).

Feel free to comment if you need any help .